# Convergence divergence of $\sum \frac{n^4}{e^{n^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check the Convergence divergence of $\sum \frac{n^4}{e^{n^2}}$

I applied ratio test. But I am not feeling sure. Is ratio test ok here, or some other way is possible.

Comment: Yes ratio test is perfectly okay here.

Comment: Ok thanks so much...

Comment: If any of these answers satisfied your question, kindly pick one, or further refine your confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Hint

For $n>N$,we have
$$e^{n^2}>n^{5+p},p>0\Longrightarrow \dfrac{n^4}{e^{n^2}}<\dfrac{1}{n^{1+p}}$$

Answer (score 3):

From the ratio test $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{\frac{(n+1)^4}{e^{(n+1)^2}}}{\frac{n^4}{e^{n^2}}}| = \lim_{n\to\infty}{(\frac{n+1}{n})}^4e^{n^2 - (n+1)^2}$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac1n)^4e^{-2n-1} = 0 < 1$

So this series converges.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^4}{e^{n^2}}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{4/n}}{e^n}=0<1$ $\;\;$(since $n^{4/n}\to1$ and $e^n\to\infty$),

so the series converges by the Root Test.